# Populate Gridview With Firebase Using Hashmap

Tags: android, firebase, hashmap, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to populate my gridview using Hashmap but i'm facing this problem:

using this code to get data (books info) from firebase and populate my gridview I get an empty grid view:

```
 mDatabasee = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabasee.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.child("Items").getChildren()) {

                Item person = postSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);
                Log.d("picture",person.getBookImage());
                hm.put(postSnapshot.getKey().toString(),person.getBookImage());
                String number = String.valueOf(hm.size());
                Log.d("count",number);
```

this Log.d return count : 1 exactly like I have in firebase

```
 }
            for(Map.Entry m:hm.entrySet()){
                System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());

            }

        }

        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

    String number = String.valueOf(hm.size());
    Log.d("css css css",number);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, hm));
```

the last Log.d return 
    "css css css 0"
so it's normal that I'm receiving an empty grid view, to make sure i have added manually 1 book so the new code become:

```
hm.put("-KWyZJM9GhhTe1PzuJMh","http://books.google.com/books/content?id=aJeTCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api");
    String number = String.valueOf(hm.size());
    Log.d("css css css",number);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, hm));
```

Comment: after adding manually this book i was able to populate gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must notify the adapter of changes.

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, hm); // Stored as member variable
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

within the firebase method, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`